# iprof and iprof_totals profiling error

Tags: openmdao

I get this error after trying :

```
openmdao iprof x.py
```

or

```
openmdao iprof_totals x.py
```

on my terminal. Any idea why it could be? Do we have a simple sample code where the iprof works smoothly.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/bin/openmdao", line 11, in 
    sys.exit(openmdao_cmd())
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openmdao/utils/om.py", line 403, in openmdao_cmd
    options.executor(options)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openmdao/devtools/iprofile.py", line 373, in _iprof_totals_exec
    _iprof_py_file(options)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openmdao/devtools/iprofile.py", line 429, in _iprof_py_file
    _finalize_profile()
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openmdao/devtools/iprofile.py", line 183, in _finalize_profile
    qfile, qclass, qname = find_qualified_name(filename, int(line), cache, full=False)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openmdao/devtools/iprof_utils.py", line 73, in find_qualified_name
    with open(filename, 'Ur') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'packages/openmdao/jacobians/jacobian.py'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into this and there is currently a bug when using 'openmdao iprof' and 'openmdao iprof_totals' on a version of OpenMDAO that was not installed from an OpenMDAO repository using 'pip install -e'.  I put a story in our bug tracker to fix it.

Comment: OK, this has now been fixed on the OpenMDAO master branch on github.  It will make it into the next release, but I'm not sure when that will happen.